# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > No such property: config for class: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle

I am using firebase for my android app and  I am getting an error when I tried to run the app. after adding firabase Storage to my project.
I got this error :
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No such property: config for class: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin

dependencies in my build.gradle(:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.carrental"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
}

com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is my build.gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
```

those should be in same version and the version must be compatible with :

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'